# How to know first questions asked for [android] tag in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search

I want to know how can I able to see the very first question asked by anyone from Stack Overflow for [android](/questions/tagged/android).

I have searched many ways in Stack Overflow and googled it but could not able to get the very first question asked on Stack Overflow. I wanted to know how the questions was asked by people at an very early stage when android OS just started to develop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the [tagged page (tagged android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) -> Click on [*newest*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&pagesize=50) -> redirect to [the last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?page=6954&sort=newest&pagesize=50) -> And click on [the last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10256/1369235).

However this doesn't guarantee you that it is the first question because it is possible that the first question have been deleted.

Comment: This also excludes any questions that were once tagged as ' android' but were edited away.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer will show the oldest question with the android tag based on the *question*'s creation date, [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120874/old-android-questions) data.SE query  show you the oldest tagged question as android [still exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256), and is owned by [Haydar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/288).

Of course, data.SE still doesn't include deleted question info; so we can't be sure, but Haydar **does** have the taxonomists badge, making it a high possibility that he is the official owner.

Comment: Note that while the same results exist for both of our answers, if a question wasn't tagged as android on creation, then it won't show up in my query.

Comment: Haydar got the badge for the creation of [tag:virtual]... http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=288, *sigh*.